# CSS drop down padding not working properly

Tags: css

I made a simple CSS drop-down menu but am facing some issues with padding. When I hover on an element, I want the new background color to nicely fill the whole elements, but it's just limited to the text right now. Could someone please have a look and tell me what's wrong: **http://jsfiddle.net/2pdxx4fq/**

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Attendance</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Leave</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Holidays</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
 *  v2.0 | 20110126
 *  License: none (public domain)
 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
        content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* ========= End of CSS Reset ============ */


#navbar {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    background-color: #444;
}

#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
    color: #000;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}

#navbar li ul {
    background-color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#navbar li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
#navbar a:hover {
```

To this:

```
#navbar li:hover {
```

That way will be the whole `li` element what will change on hover, not just the anchor `a`.

Comment: But then the second-level elements are having trouble. Look at Upload below Attendance, for instance. Why is there the extra space to the right?

Comment: That is because the `li` element isn't filling the whole area. That's a complete different issue. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It gets fix adding this: `#navbar li > ul > li{display: block;}`

Comment: This line: `#navbar li > ul > li` is indicating that the style will be applied on elements nested this way: `<li><ul><li></li></ul></li>` The **CSS** rule `display: block` to those elements is to make sure they will fill the whole area. Got it?

Comment: Yes, I understood the selector and just read up on block-level elements. I learned that they stretch left and right as far as possible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Apply the hover on `li`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2pdxx4fq/3/)

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
 *  v2.0 | 20110126
 *  License: none (public domain)
 */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* ========= End of CSS Reset ============ */

#navbar {
  margin: 20px 0px;
  background-color: #444;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#navbar li:hover {
  background-color: #AAA;
  color: #000;
}
#navbar li ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar li ul {
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#navbar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Attendance</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Upload</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Report</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Leave</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Report</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Holidays</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Log out</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow the first-level elements are crawling on top of each other. Could it be problem with the width you set?

Comment: @dotslash - Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/2pdxx4fq/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from `li` and add it to `a` along with `display:block` (also on the anchor).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pdxx4fq/4/)